# JavaScript partial match object property in loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I transform this array of object

```
const arr = [{
  my_first_name_1: {
    value: 'jane'
  },
  my_last_name_1: {
    value: 'anderson'
  }
}, {
  my_first_name_2: {
    value: 'alex'
  },
  my_last_name_2: {
    value: 'johnson'
  }
}]
```

into this?

```
[{
  "first_name": "jane",
  "last_name": "anderson",
}, {
  "first_name": "alex",
  "last_name": "johnson",
}]
```

I'm stuck at matching the property with partial string

```
const result = arr.reduce((accum, obj) => {
   obj.match(first_name)  //how to do partial matching? Tried .includes but it doesn't work
}, [])
```

Comment: Can you change the source of that "monstrosity"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), read from the documentations:

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
>
> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them.

Try as the following:

```js
const arr = [{ my_first_name_1: { value: 'jane' }, my_last_name_1: { value: 'anderson'} }, { my_first_name_2: { value: 'alex' }, my_last_name_2: { value: 'johnson' } }];
  
const result = arr.map((e, i) => ({
  first_name: e[`my_first_name_${i + 1}`].value,
  last_name: e[`my_last_name_${i + 1}`].value
}))

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Template strings have no advantage over simple string concatenation: `"my_first_name_" + (i + 1)`

Comment: @Andreas That's correct but for some reason I like to use them instead concatenating strings. Maybe this is just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

If your keys aren't sequential, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). The `.map()` method will iterate over every object in your array, which you can then get the values of using `Object.values()`. From the array of values (which are objects), you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the objects `value` property and alias them as `first_name` and `last_name`. You can then returned these two destructured values as an object:

```js
const arr = [{ my_first_name_1: { value: 'jane' }, my_last_name_1: { value: 'anderson' } }, { my_first_name_2: { value: 'alex' }, my_last_name_2: { value: 'johnson' } }];

const res = arr.map(obj => {
  const [{value: first_name}, {value: last_name}] = Object.values(obj); 
  return {first_name, last_name};
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the keys of each object, and then get their value with `reduce()`

```js
const arr = [{
    my_first_name_1: {
      value: "jane",
    },
    my_last_name_1: {
      value: "anderson",
    },
  },
  {
    my_first_name_2: {
      value: "alex",
    },
    my_last_name_2: {
      value: "johnson",
    },
  },
];

let result = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
  let [first, last] = Object.keys(c);
  return [...p, {
    first_name: c[first].value,
    last_name: c[last].value,
  }];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```